# SQL Pivot Table for

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get a list to pivot in SQL, but I get an error.

SQL Table_1

| id | res_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 3 | 102 |
| 4 | 103 |

SQL Table_2

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Title 1 |
| 2 | Title 2 |
| 3 | Title 3 |
| 4 | Title 4 |

My aim is to get an output that looks something like;

| res_id | doc1 | doc2 | doc3 | doc4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Title 1 | Title 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 102 | Title 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 103 | Title 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

My Code Currently looks like this;

```
    SELECT res_id, doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4
    FROM    (   SELECT DISTINCT a.res_id, b.title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.res_id ORDER BY b.title) AS line_no
            FROM table_2 b
            INNER JOIN table_1 a ON a.id = b.id
            WHERE b.index = {value}
        ) AS p
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(title)
            FOR line_no IN ([doc1], [doc2], [doc3], [doc4])
        ) AS pvt
```

When I run it, I get the following errors and wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction;

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.
> Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> The incorrect value "doc1" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

Comment: *"Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier."* this error is very specific; however, in the data you've supplied you have no `uniqueidentifier`. I feel like we're missing details here.

Comment: I was playing around, and tried converting the row_number to biginit as the original message was

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: Also, you reference the column `b.index`, but there is no column `index` in your sample data. Also, that would fail, because `INDEX` is a reserved keyword and you don't delimit identify the column name. Take the time to provide us with a [mre] using DDL and DML..

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(
   id     INT  NOT NULL
  ,res_id INT  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #table1(id,res_id) VALUES
 (1,101),(2,101),(3,102),(4,103);

CREATE TABLE #table2(
   id    INT  NOT NULL
  ,title VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #table2(id,title) VALUES
 (1,'Title 1'),(2,'Title 2'),(3,'Title 3'),(4,'Title 4');

--Maybe ?? 

WITH CTE
AS (SELECT
  t1.res_id,
  t2.title,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.res_id ORDER BY t1.id) RN
FROM #table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN #table2 AS t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id)


SELECT        
res_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN TITLE ELSE NULL END) AS doc1,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN TITLE ELSE NULL END) AS doc2,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN TITLE ELSE NULL END) AS doc3,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN TITLE ELSE NULL END) AS doc4
FROM  CTE
GROUP BY res_id

DROP TABLE #table1
DROP TABLE #table2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight problem with the `pivot` portion in your query as the *line_no* should be one of *1,2,3 or 4*.

Please try the following:

```
SELECT res_id, [1] as doc1, [2] as doc2, [3] as doc3, [4] as doc4
FROM    
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.res_id, b.title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.res_id ORDER BY b.title) AS line_no
    FROM tab2 b
    INNER JOIN tab1 a ON a.id = b.id
    --WHERE b.index = {value}
) AS p
PIVOT
(   
    MAX(title)
    FOR line_no IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS pvt
```

Please find the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c2e0f4c4cc3e76e26119cc18bb702bdf).